# OR match for HTML::TreeBuilder's look_down feature

Tags: regex, perl, html-treebuilder

Trying to match `tr` items that have a `class` with *either* the first three letters starting with `eve` or `day`. This is my attempt:

```
my @stuff = $p->look_down(
    _tag => 'tr',
    class => 'qr/eve*|day*/g'
);

foreach (@stuff) {
        print $_->as_text;
};
```

Just curious, what kind of objects are in `@stuff`?

---

Is this OK? See below:

```
my @stuff = $p->look_down(
    _tag => 'tr',
    class => qr/eve.*|day.*/
);

print "\n\n";

foreach (@stuff) {
        print $_->as_text . "\n\n";
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to anchor your regex with `^` in order for the class to match the first three letters.

The following achieves what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(do {local $/; <DATA>});

foreach my $tr ($p->look_down(_tag => 'tr', class => qr{^(?:eve|day)})) {
    print $tr->as_text, "\n";
};

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<p>hi</p>
<table>
<tr class="notme"><td colspan=2>row 1 is bad</td></tr>
<tr class="not_eve_or_day"><td colspan=2>row 2 is bad</td></tr>
<tr class="everyrow"><td colspan=2>row 3 is good 1 of 2</td></tr>
<tr class="dayme"><td colspan=2>row 4 is good 2 of 2</td></tr>
<tr class="notme"><td colspan=2>row 5 is bad</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
row 3 is good 1 of 2
row 4 is good 2 of 2
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any disadvantage to my doing it as show at the bottom of my post?

Comment: The only potential advantage I know with my code is that the regular expression actually works.  Fix your regex, and you're good to go.

Comment: It's not anchored, so it would print row 2 in my example.

Comment: What are the symbols I need to use to anchor it? I assume that "anchor" means `eve` is how it starts and the `e` is the beginning.

Comment: Just look at my code.  I've already demonstrated the regex that you want.